# What do you call a person who expresses strong opinions on things they know nothing about?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there a word to describe a person who habitually expresses strong opinions on a subject without having any facts or background knowledge to base their opinion on.
Examples include many politicians, the media when they don’t do research, and many loud opinionated people who “Like the sound of their own voice”.
With so many words in our language with very specific meanings it seems a single word to describe this [commonly occurring] situation would useful?

Comment: You came up with opinionated yourself, that fits just fine assuming that a word functioning as an adjective is what you're after, are you?

Comment: Please provide a sample sentence per the SWR tag:"This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used."

Comment: A common term these days is **bloviator**.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need two words to capture the contradiction inherent in the type of person you describe. So, given that, how about **arrogant ignoramus**?

[**Arrogant**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arrogant) (M-W): exaggerating or disposed to exaggerate one's own worth or importance often by an overbearing manner

[**Ignoramus**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ignoramus) (M-W): an utterly ignorant person

I also like SteveSliva's suggestion of *uninformed blowhard*, which is in the same vein as *arrogant ignoramus*.